# Creating SQL Server format file to use with bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I want to bulk insert a big pile of data into SQL Server, and thus, I need a format file (I'm not inserting value into all columns).

But using [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server) and the `bcp AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department format nul -c -x -f Department-c..xml –t, -T` format, I get an error, pointing at the `-t,` bit, saying ParentContainsErrorException saying there are missing arguments.

What's wrong with the above?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You need to select the data. Do you want to output it to an xml file?

Comment: What do you mean I need to select the data? I am, much like I wrote, trying to create a model file to use with bulk insert. I have followed the linked guide, using the above quoted syntax, and then get the error I listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your path to where you want your xml file.

This here works for me:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000)
SET @str = 'bcp AdventureWorks2014.HumanResources.Department format nul -c -x -f D:\Stack\Department-c.xml -t, -T'  
EXEC xp_cmdshell @str
GO
```

Given the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="7"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="DepartmentID" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Name" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="GroupName" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="ModifiedDate" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson The reason why they suggest a CMD is because BCP is actually an executable file. BCP.exe which you can call from command prompt. But i find it easier to use SQL :)

Comment: One weird thing though, bulk insert then complains that "Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query." I am trying to insert two identical DateTime fields into two different columns. Both are DateTime, one allows NULL, the other doesn't. They look like this in the model: <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="NativeFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson can you make a new question with the code you use for insert. And show the data of your date columns

Comment: Sure thing, the new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47829486/ms-sql-failing-to-bulk-insert-with-xml-model