# Failing to bulk insert with XML model

Tags: sql-server, xml, bulkinsert

I am trying to use `BULK INSERT` to insert a large amount of binary files with metadata into a SQL Server table. I want to only specify a subset of the columns to use (most importantly, the PK is a `UniqueIdentifier` and I want SQL Server to generate this field). And so I must use a model file.

Not using a model file (entering data for all columns) works fine with this file:

```
00000000-F436-49D0-B5A9-02DAB2E03F45, B, , , , JVBERio4MjEzNQ0KJSVFT0Y=, 109754, 2017-12-14 14:53:23, 2017-12-14 14:53:23, number, name
```

And this statement:

```
BULK INSERT Documents
FROM 'c:\temp\testdata.txt'
WITH
(
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
  ROWS_PER_BATCH = 1000, 
  FIRSTROW = 1,
  TABLOCK
)
```

But when I try to use a model file, I have run into two different problems. Firstly, when using a model file that specifies all columns:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="10" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="10" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="8" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="NativeFixed" LENGTH="4"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="NativeFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="DocumentId" xsi:type="SQLUNIQUEID"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="DocumentType" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="CompanyCode" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="CustomerNumber" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="OrderNumber" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="Data" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="Size" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="Created" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="Modified" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="InvoiceNumber" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="Title" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

and this statement:

```
BULK INSERT Documents   
   FROM 'c:\Temp\testiness.txt'   
   WITH
   (
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
      ROWS_PER_BATCH = 1000, 
      FIRSTROW = 1,
      TABLOCK,
      FORMATFILE = 'c:\Temp\modeltest.xml'
   );  
GO
```

I get this error:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 2. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".`

And when using this reduced model file (and atext file with fewer values):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="10" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="10" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="8" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="NativeFixed" LENGTH="4"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="NativeFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="DocumentType" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="CompanyCode" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="CustomerNumber" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="OrderNumber" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Data" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="Size" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="Created" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="Modified" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="Title" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

I get:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: Whenever I have large numbers of files to import into SQL Server I typically use Powershell especially if the import isn't a one off . It allows me to use .Net objects to validate and the import the data quickly and very efficiently.

Comment: I wish I had time to learn powershell :)

Comment: It is fairly simple take a look at this link: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Import-Large-CSVs-into-SQL-216223d9 and you can schedule this script to run natively inside of a Sql Agent job

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to import this data into a tolerant staging table and continue from there. Just one observation:

```
<FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="NativeFixed" LENGTH="8"/>
<FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>
<FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100">
```

Correspond to

```
<COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="Size" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
<COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="Created" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
<COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="Modified" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
```

Nr 7 seems to be an `INT` (8 byte is to much though), while 8 and 9 point to date value (by the column's names and types), while the `<FIELD>` definition is not consistent.